# Fonts not working in development - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fonts, sass

I have an arabic font I would like to use in my website, which works fine in development, but for some reason it does not work in production. The way im loading the font to my project is this:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/earlyaccess/droidarabickufi.css);
```

Im not sure if this is the correct way, if not please advise me on how I can make this particular font to work on my project in both development and production.

Comment: I am thinking that your assets are not loaded in the production env. Inspect element on the css assets of your webpage to see that this particular css file is really loaded. There are a variety of reasons for it. Forgot to precompile assets? Never require in application.scss file?